# How do you overload the << operator in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, operators, operator-overloading

I'm not sure how to accomplish overloading the << operator for a method. This is how I assumed it would work:

```
def roles<<(roles)
  ...  
end
```

That however, throws errors. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to do that from within a class. Like this:

```
class Whatever
  attr_accessor :roles
  def initialize
    @roles = []
  end
end
```

You can't really have a `<<roles` method. You'd have to have an accessor for `roles` that supports the `<<` operator.

EDIT: I've updated the code. Now you can see how the `<<` operator should be overloaded, but you can also do what the `roles<<` part. Here's a small snippet of it's usage:

```
w = Whatever.new
w << "overload for object called"
# and overloads for the roles array
w.roles << "first role"
w.roles << "second role"
```

Comment: In your solution w.roles is not calling the overridden << method. It's just calling the << on the @roles attribute, which is not overridden. You can test this by adding a puts line in the overridden << method and you'll see that doing `w << "1"` dumps the puts output but w.roles << "2" does NOT dump that puts output.